# Jquery change select syntax right after this dropdown menu is loaded from another page

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have the following code that loads element from a remote page (under same domain) into the current page. The element #Anhui contains a dropdown menu, and I wish to add some value into the menu in select syntax after it is loaded. The value I would like to add is:

```
size="5" onChange="this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=this[this.selectedIndex].value"
```

and here is the event code I've got, please help me to edit it furthur, thank you.

```
function StateAnhui() { 
$('#SuburbSelect').load('/Country/CN/_CN_suburbs.html #Anhui'); 
}
```

**this is the dropdown menu loaded in:**

```
<div id="Anhui">
<fieldset class="suburbSelect">
<label for="suburbSelect">安徽 / Province  </label> 
<select>

    <option value="合肥">合肥</option>
    <option value="巢湖">巢湖</option>
    <option value="蚌埠">蚌埠</option>
    <option value="安庆">安庆</option>
    <option value="六安">六安</option>
    <option value="滁州">滁州</option>
    <option value="马鞍山">马鞍山</option>
    <option value="阜阳">阜阳</option>
    <option value="宣城">宣城</option>
    <option value="铜陵">铜陵</option>
    <option value="淮北">淮北</option>
    <option value="芜湖">芜湖</option>
    <option value="宿州">宿州</option>
    <option value="淮南">淮南</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

**After loaded, I want the dropdown to be like this:**

```
<div id="Anhui">
<fieldset class="suburbSelect">
<label for="suburbSelect">安徽 / Province  </label> 
<select size="5" onChange="this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=this[this.selectedIndex].value">

    <option value="合肥">合肥</option>
    <option value="巢湖">巢湖</option>
    <option value="蚌埠">蚌埠</option>
    <option value="安庆">安庆</option>
    <option value="六安">六安</option>
    <option value="滁州">滁州</option>
    <option value="马鞍山">马鞍山</option>
    <option value="阜阳">阜阳</option>
    <option value="宣城">宣城</option>
    <option value="铜陵">铜陵</option>
    <option value="淮北">淮北</option>
    <option value="芜湖">芜湖</option>
    <option value="宿州">宿州</option>
    <option value="淮南">淮南</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Can't you just use a jquery function for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#Anhui select').change(function(){

 $(this).attr('size', 5) ;
this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=$(this).val();

});

});
```